# Data Grid View multi querystring issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I am getting only  the `ItemID` from `querystring` in  `gridview`.But I want to  display the link in `querystring`.

**`gridview` properties:**

- `DataNavigateUrlFields`: `ItemID`, `Link`.
- `DataNavigateUrlFormatString`: `OpenLink.aspx?itemid={0}&link={1}`.

Here  `ItemID` is *pk* and auto generated field of `Item` Table, it'll upgrade whenever data will be  saved in the database.

`Link` column is the  http link of that data from Item Table and its a hyperlink template in the `gridview` and  it displays the title of data in `hyperlinkfield`.

My main aim is to get the value of `ItemID` and link from the `querystring` so that I can display it to another .aspx page.

Comment: So what is the issue you are getting ?

Comment: @VeeKeyBee I am getting only ItemID from querystring whereas I need both the column value ,ItemID and Link as a result of querystring.

Comment: Could you pls show us the complete URL when clicking on the hyperlink?

Comment: @Franz if I edit my  gridview property like this below and remove the link as I described earlier in my quiestion:

DataNavigateUrlFields: ItemID
DataNavigateUrlFormatString: OpenLink.aspx?itemid={0}

I am getting this url when I click on hyperlink :

http://localhost:1087/OpenLink.aspx?itemid=1

but somehow I need both the value ItemID and Link but if I modify the gridview property as like this:

DataNavigateUrlFields: ItemID, Link.
DataNavigateUrlFormatString: OpenLink.aspx?itemid={0}&link={1}.

HyperlinkButton is not working then and I am  unable to open any data link.

Comment: @Franz I tried your code and I appriciate your effort but that too din't worked.

Comment: If you are using my piece of code what exactly does your hyperlink look like (what url is it showing). your Hyperlink button may not work as your link may invalid chars for a queryString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a quick demo and tried what you described. Apparently the *HyperLink column* is *not able to Encode* your given link from *DataNavigateUrlFields*. So I created a **templateField** and a **custom method** and voilá

```
// code behind
public string createUrl(object itemName, object link)
{
     return string.Format("showItem.aspx?itemID={0}&link={1}",
         itemName.ToString(),
         HttpUtility.UrlEncode(link.ToString()));
}
```

in combination with...

[image: ASPX page design view]

results in ...

[image: Chrome view of ASPX page]

As you can see, your described behaviour occurs when just make use of **DataNavigateUrlXXX**. A few lines above you can see my code.

Anyway be aware of any kind of queryString manipulation, and **check** your given **queryString** values at showItem.aspx. You may have a look at [securing queryStrings](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33350/Encrypting-Query-Strings) or [this example](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/security/encrypting-query-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for one of my projects.  The code is below.  I hope it helps.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkViewRequest" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "./ViewRequest.aspx?Database=" & Request.QueryString("Database") & "&RequestNumber=" & Eval("Request") %>' Text="View"></asp:HyperLink>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Here I used a value passed in from a QueryString and then added a value from the gridrow to add a second querystring to the outgoing URL.